# Will storing arrays of arrays in user defaults slow down my iOS app? (Is Core Data better for this?)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, userdefaults

I'm working on a program that lets users upload images from their photo library. The images are stored using a File Manager, and I use user defaults to store unique integer keys so that I can pull the images back. The array of keys looks something like this:

```
var images: [[Int]] = userDefaults.array(forKey: "myKey") as? [[Int]] ?? [[0], [1000], [2000], [3000], [4000]]
```

These are displayed in a Collection View with 5 different sections, hence the five different arrays. I stop the user from uploading any more images after 1,000 per section. When testing using the simulator, after uploading ~30 images total, it starts lagging. When I tested it on my phone, it completely crashed after ~20 images.

I've been testing out Core Data instead, hoping that my app won't be as laggy. For now, I only created one entity to hold all the images. But I run into the same problem where the simulator starts to lag after ~30 images are uploaded.

I then thought maybe it's how I'm storing data in the File Manager. Originally, I was saving the images as png data, so I tried using jpeg data instead (with a compression size of 0). This still didn't help and my app is still lagging :(

I'm still pretty new to iOS, so any help would be appreciated!

VIEW CONTROLLER:

```css
//
//  ViewController.swift
//
//

import UIKit
import PhotosUI
import Photos
import CoreData 
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

// user images below
var currentImageType = String()

// arbitrary numbers so that the image names differ from eachother
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
var images: [[Int]] = userDefaults.array(forKey: "myKey") as? [[Int]] ?? [[0], [1000], [2000], [3000], [4000]]

class ViewController: UIViewController, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    
    // when trash is pressed in ClosetDetailViewController, return to ViewController
    @IBAction func unwindToCloset(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        
        // popup menu items
        let tops = UIAction(title: "tops") { (action) in
              print("tops!")
            self.addPhotos(categoryType: "tops")
         }
         let outerwear = UIAction(title: "outerwear") { (action) in
             print("outerwear!")
             self.addPhotos(categoryType: "outerwear")
         }
         let bottoms = UIAction(title: "bottoms") { (action) in
              print("bottoms!")
             self.addPhotos(categoryType: "bottoms")
         }
        let singles = UIAction(title: "singles") { (action) in
             print("singles!")
            self.addPhotos(categoryType: "singles")
        }
        let accessories = UIAction(title: "accessories") { (action) in
             print("accessories!")
            self.addPhotos(categoryType: "accessories")
        }
        let menu = UIMenu(title: "my closet", options: .displayInline,
                           children: [tops, outerwear, bottoms, singles, accessories])
        
        // set up collection in closet
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .add, menu: menu)]
        collectionView.register(ClosetCollectionViewCell.nib(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ClosetCollectionViewCell")
        
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 75, height: 100)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 14
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 14
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 7, left: 5, bottom: 7, right: 5)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    // access photo library
    @objc private func addPhotos(categoryType: String) {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.selectionLimit = 100
        config.filter = .images
        let vc = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true)
        currentImageType = categoryType
    }
    
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        results.forEach { result in
            group.enter()
            result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { reading, error in
                defer {
                    group.leave()
                }
                guard let image = reading as? UIImage, error == nil else {
                    return
                }

                
                func saveByType(Type: Int) {
                    images[Type].append(images[Type].last! + 1)
                    userDefaults.set(images, forKey: "myKey")
                    
                    LocalFileManager.instance.saveImage(image: image, imageName: String(images[Type].last!), folderName: "closet")

                }
                
                switch currentImageType {
                case "tops": saveByType(Type: 0)
                case "outerwear": saveByType(Type: 1)
                case "bottoms": saveByType(Type: 2)
                case "singles": saveByType(Type: 3)
                case "accessories": saveByType(Type: 4)
                default: saveByType(Type: 0)
                    print("no type chosen")
                }
                
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            // print(images)
            // userDefaults.set(images, forKey: "myKey")
        }
    }
}


extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print("you tapped me!")
        // set closetImageName in ClosetDetailViewController
        detailImageName = images[indexPath.section][indexPath.item + 1]
        print(detailImageName)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "closetDetail", sender: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // how many cells are shown? based on number of items the user uploaded
        return images[section].count - 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // return cell for given item
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ClosetCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ClosetCollectionViewCell
        
        // show every cell in image array
        cell.imageView.image = LocalFileManager.instance.getImage(imageName: String(images[indexPath.section][indexPath.item + 1]), folderName: "closet")
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    // margin of padding between cells
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 75, height: 100)
    }
    
}
```

FILE MANAGER:

```css
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class LocalFileManager {
    static let instance = LocalFileManager()
    private init() {}
    
    enum StorageType {
        case userDefaults
        case fileSystem
    }
    
    private func filePath(forKey key: String) -> URL? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        guard let documentURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).first else { return nil }
        
        return documentURL.appendingPathComponent(key + ".png")
    }
    
    private func store(image: UIImage, forKey key: String, withStorageType storageType: StorageType) {
        if let pngRepresentation = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0) {
            switch storageType {
            case .fileSystem:
                if let filePath = filePath(forKey: key) {
                    do  {
                        try pngRepresentation.write(to: filePath,
                                                    options: .atomic)
                    } catch let err {
                        print("Saving file resulted in error: ", err)
                    }
                }
            case .userDefaults:
                UserDefaults.standard.set(pngRepresentation, forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func retrieveImage(forKey key: String, inStorageType storageType: StorageType) -> UIImage? {
        switch storageType {
        case .fileSystem:
            if let filePath = self.filePath(forKey: key),
                let fileData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath.path),
                let image = UIImage(data: fileData) {
                return image
            }
        case .userDefaults:
            if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Data,
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                
                return image
            }
        }
        return nil 
    }
    
    
    func saveImage(image: UIImage, imageName: String, folderName: String) {

        // create folder
        createFolderIfNeeded(folderName: folderName)
        // get path for image
        guard
            let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0),
            let url = getURLforImage(imageName: imageName, folderName: folderName)
        else { return  }
        // save image to path
        do {
            try data.write(to: url)
        } catch let error {
            print("image name: \(image) error saving image: \(error)")
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: imageName)
    }
    
    
    func getImage(imageName: String, folderName: String) -> UIImage? {
        guard let url = getURLforImage(imageName: imageName, folderName: folderName),
              FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        return UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path)
    }
    
    
    // referenced functions below
    
    // create folder to store images
    private func createFolderIfNeeded(folderName: String) {
        guard let url = getURLforFolder(folderName: folderName) else {
            return
        }
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
            }
            catch let error {
                print("folder name: \(folderName) error creating folder! \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    // get URL for that folder
    private func getURLforFolder(folderName: String) -> URL? {
        guard let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
        else {
            return nil
        }
        return url.appendingPathExtension(folderName)
    }
    
    // generate URL for images in folder
    private func getURLforImage(imageName: String, folderName: String) -> URL? {
        guard let folderURL = getURLforFolder(folderName: folderName) else {
            return nil
        }
        return folderURL.appendingPathExtension(imageName)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect UserDefaults to be slow, but it is more difficult to store lots of data in. You have to read/write all of the data at once since it isn't record based and unless you are careful it is easy for bugs to result in lost data. Core data sounds like a better fit for what you are trying to do, but your root problem is elsewhere.  How large are the images? Are you trying to load them all into memory at once to display in the collection view?  It sounds like you are simply trying to hold too much in memory at once.

Comment: The images aren't too large, I've been using the sample ones in the Xcode simulator. When displayed in the collection view, they're 75 x 100 pixels. I might eventually make the switch to Core Data, but for now I'm trying to figure out a better way to store/load images. Is there a way to stagger it? I've researched the lazy load method but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: It doesn't matter what size you display the image on screen, the full image is loaded, uncompressed, into memory when you use `UIImage`. The sample images in the simulator are all 2-3mB.  If you only need a thumbnail, load the image, resize it to get the thumbnail and then release the original image from memory.

Comment: Without actual code, this is all just hand waving. "When I tested it on my phone, it completely crashed after ~20 images." Yep, well, show me that code so I can experience the same thing. Because currently I have no idea at all what you're doing other than mishandling images.

Comment: @matt updated just for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is probably too many active image references.

To diagnose, and provide further insight, you need to run your app with the Allocations instrument.

Choose menu option `Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Instruments` and then pick `Allocations`.  You may want to check out [Getting started with Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/) video as part of WWDC2019 to get going.

One tell-tale is that you have found the simulator can work with more images than the phone.  This is because the memory limits on the simulator are much higher.

Comment: Just tried this out! It definitely spikes after adding in each image. After 10, I received this message: "The data volume is too high for a recoding mode of "Immediate" and some data had to be dropped to move forward. Recovery Suggestion: Try setting recording mode to "Deferred" and restarting the trace." Not sure if this is talking about the allocation or the actual program

Comment: Wow.  I suggest changing your program to temporary just work with 9 images, collect the data and then explore the issue.  In your case, more images are not needed to identify the problem.